# HighChart Shared Tooltip Number Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, number-formatting

I'm using HighCharts JS for the very first time. So far, I'm very impressed. I'm charting multiples series and using a shared tooltip. The numbers in the shared tooltip are correct, but they are not formatted as I would like. For example, I'm seeing `9876` instead of `9,876`.

I know that I can use the formatter to completely customize the tooltip. Instead of completely redoing the tooltip, I'd just like to format the number and keep the existing look and feel.

**Question:** Is is possible to specify a format for the number(s) in the tooltip without writing a custom formatter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible, I am afraid: the default tooltip formatters are somewhat hidden inside the `Point` and `Tooltip` objects and do not provide access to the number formatting.

However, you may want to globally override the default implementation of a `Point`'s `tooltipFormatter` with something of your own, e.g.

```
Highcharts.Point.prototype.tooltipFormatter = function (useHeader) {
    var point = this, series = point.series;
    return ['<span style="color:' + series.color + '">', (point.name || series.name), '</span>: ',
        (!useHeader ? ('<b>x = ' + (point.name || point.x) + ',</b> ') : ''),
        '<b>', (!useHeader ? 'y = ' : ''), Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 0), '</b>'].join('');
};
```

This implementation is the same as the default one except for the `Highcharts.numberFormat` call on the last line, which will do your number formatting.

Keep in mind that such a change will apply to all your charts.

Comment: I **hate** when people ask follow up questions in the comments. But, here I go: Is there any way to align the text right so that if the series names aren't the same length, the text still looks neat and aligned?

Comment: By default the tooltip labels are rendered as SVG and allow only very few formatting style options, unfortunately nothing relevant to alignment as it seems (documentation says _only text-related CSS that is shared with SVG is handled_). One can in fact set `useHTML: true` as an option for the chart's tooltips and replace the e.g. `<b>` tag on the last line of the above code by something like `<b style="position: absolute; right: 0">`, but there seem to be some nasty rendering problems when using HTML (the label boxes are not always properly resized). Further investigation is necessary...

Comment: Late to the party, appealing on some understanding of how and why the answer is necessary. Highcharts has a configurable `thousandsSep` property under its configuration localisation options, and its default is the comma separator (`,`) — to me this more than implies that default number string presentation (regardless of context and containing markup) would have thousands separated by a comma, and yet that isn't the case. How come this is unrelated to the question?

Answer (score 3):

Use `pointFormatter` to format shared tooltip. This is available since version 4.1.0:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormatter: function() { 
        return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + ';">●</span> ' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + numberFormat(this.y) + '</b><br/>'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: This answer is _exactly_ what I've been searching for!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.2 there is a new option "pointFormat" to specify a separate formater for the pointvalues only:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat

Answer (score -1):

The way to apply `Math.round()` function inside the highchart script.

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'CPU (GHz)',
    data: [
            ['Used',Math.round( <?php echo $gSum_Allocated_CPU; ?>, 2)],
            {
                name: 'Available',
                y:Math.round(<?php echo $gSum_Available_CPU; ?>, 2),
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
             }
          ]
     }]
```